# How close is the game rules of Cardfight!! Vanguard in the anime compared to the actual game?

Tags: cardfight-vanguard

From my experience with game-based anime which you can actually play like *Yu-Gi-Oh* and *Bakugan*, the rules of the game in the anime is vastly different from that in real life game. For example, 1st season of *Yu-Gi-Oh* didn't require sacrifices for stronger monsters, and Yugi didn't automatically win by having a single piece of Exodia. In the Battle City Arc, when Joey fights a Rare Hunter, he has 3 of every piece while the rules state you can only have 1.

Since *Cardfight!! Vanguard* is in a way like *Yu-Gi-Oh* in which it has a real life card game (not sure if the anime is based off the game or vice versa), I am wondering if the game rules of *Cardfight!! Vanguard* in the anime is the same as that of the actual game itself?

Comment: The rules of the genuine card game hadn't been established when the manga wrote the plot from which the Duellist Kindgdom plot was adapted. And the Rare Hunter's set of three of each Exodia was bizarre in-universe; also, they were counterfeits.